# how does sscanf do in assembly

Tags: assembly, scanf

I have read an program in assembly and saw **msvcrt.sscanf**. I don't know how the register eax change after running sscanf. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

The result of the `sscanf` function (part of ISO C) is the number of format fields that have actually had values suppled from the string being parsed. At the assembly level, this value is returned in EAX on some architectures, probably including yours. Many C programmers ignore this value entirely — a poor practice, but common — but you *should* check it. A zero indicates a failure to parse anything, a 1 is “one field was satisfiable”, etc.

Writing a good format isn't especially easy, but reading them isn't too hard (unless there are guard fields in there too).